# Question about typesetting decimal numbers in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I can't seem to make this decimal number appear correctly.

My code is like this:

```
$S=bK^1,09$
```

I would like it to write `S = bK^(1,09)` , but instead it writes the `1` in the exponent position and then `,09` on the same baseline as `bK`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  By default only one character is placed in the superscript.  Bracketing is the correct idea, but the type of bracket tex uses for grouping is curly not round.  So writing `$S = bK^{1.09}$` will work.  For comma decimals you generally need to write `1{,}09` for correct spacing.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to encasing the number `1,09` in curly braces -- like so: `{1,09}` -- I would like to suggest that you add a layer of abstraction to the numeric input material, by (a) loading the `siunitx` package and (b) encasing numbers in `\num{...}` directives. By default, the `\num` macro recognizes both `,` and `.` as *input* decimal markers; by setting the package option `output-decimal-marker={,}`, you can direct `num` to use `,` as the decimal marker in the typeset *output*.

That way, should you one fine day decide to switch the notation convention from `,` to `.` as the decimal marker in the typeset output, all you would need to change in the document is the siunitx option, to `output-decimal-marker={.}`.

The `\num` macro is extremely versatile. For a thorough presentation of its capabilities, please see section 4.2, "Numbers", as well as sections 5.4 thru 5.8 of the [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) of the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[
S=\num{2.818}K^{\num{1,09}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Observe that the spacing around the decimal marker is automatically correct, *without* any need to encase the `,` symbol in curly braces to change its status from `math-punct` to `math-ord`.

Answer (score 3):

Use braces to isolate the exponent:

```
$S=bK^{1,09}$
```

Comment: It should also be `1{,}09` or there would be a space after the comma.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put whatever want to be superscripted in curly brackets.

```
$S=bK^{1,09}$
```

Comment: It should also be `1{,}09` or there would be a space after the comma.

Comment: @egreg I have no space in my compiled document

Comment: Just because it's at the exponent. Otherwise there would be: better being consistent.